# when i am running code in remix id it does not give error while in vs code it gives me error after installation solidity extension

Tags: solidity

// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

```js
contract Transactions {
    uint256 transactionCount;

    event Transfer(address from, address receiver, uint amount, string message, uint256 timestamp, string keyword);
  
    struct TransferStruct {
        address sender;
        address receiver;
        uint amount;
        string message;
        uint256 timestamp;
        string keyword;
    }

    TransferStruct[] transactions;

    function addToBlockchain(address payable receiver, uint amount, string memory message, string memory keyword) public {
        transactionCount += 1;
        transactions.push(TransferStruct(msg.sender, receiver, amount, message, block.timestamp, keyword));

        emit Transfer(msg.sender, receiver, amount, message, block.timestamp, keyword);
    }

    function getAllTransactions() public view returns (TransferStruct[] memory) {
        return transactions;
    }

    function getTransactionCount() public view returns (uint256) {
        return transactionCount;
    }
}
```

Comment: could you mention what error you are getting?

Comment: "Expected token Comma got 'Payable'solc"   this is the error

Answer (score 0):

If the code doesn't provide error in Remix, its fine. Solidity extensions/linters in VSCode are not a reliable source of errors.